# Identifying all points with specific attribute to polygon with same attribute using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, identify

I am working with a fairly large dataset and am trying to identify the points with a specific attribute (letter and number combination) that matches a polygon with the same attribute, but only when the point is spatially located within the matching polygon.

This may take more than one step and I have not been successful in search for the right steps.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Please [Edit] the question to contain what you have attempted, and what error you encountered.

Comment: Spatial Join polygon data to points then select by attributes where the columns match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Script will give list of all the eligible Points that have same attribute as spatially intesected Polygons. Further, you can pass this into definition query/select by attribute in point fc.

```
import arcpy

#Specify Deafult workspace for this script. it helps in - 1)all geoprocessing Output will created in this gdb. 2) you can specfiy fc with double quotes rathar than spcifying full path
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Sanjay\Documents\ArcGIS\SimilarPoints by attribute in polygon\mygdb.gdb"

#Set Output true to replace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#best practise say to use makefeaturelayer rathan spcifying fc name.
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Point","PointLayer")

#Lets do Spatial join get all intersected points with all attributes of pplygon attached
arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis("PointLayer","polygon","SelectedPoints","JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE","KEEP_ALL")

# #best practise say to use makefeaturelayer rathan spcifying fc name.
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("SelectedPoints","SelectedPoints_lyr")

#where clause to be used where ID from points and poly will match  -ID for Poly fc, ID_Point is Point Fc
sql_exp = """ID_point = ID"""

#Select by Attribute from Spatial joined FC
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("SelectedPoints_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", sql_exp)



#Lets find out what are those points features has same attribute as polgon and falls into polygon
field = 'ID_point' #Specify field to extract list of id
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("SelectedPoints_lyr", field)]
uniqueValues = set(values)#Set to get Unique id which need
print "this are ids from point fc that has same attr. and spatially located in polygon"
for item in uniqueValues:

    print item
```